# Android React Native App HostNameVerifier Error from Google Play Store

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, android-security

Please help, I have the below implementation in MainApplication.java file. I am checking fixed hostnames and then returning true or false accordingly.

> Error Insecure hostname verifier
>
> Security Your app is using an unsafe implementation of hostname
> verifier. Please see this Google Help Centre article for details,
> including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.
>
> Ld/a/a/a/a/c/e$1; Ld/a/a/a/a/c/f$1; sv:deadline:12/10/2020

```
 @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    hostnameVerifier();
    MobileCore.setApplication(this);
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    ReactNativeFirebaseApp.setApplicationContext(this);
  }

private void hostnameVerifier(){
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
      @Override
      public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
        String hostList[] = {"in.appcenter.ms", "graph.facebook.com",
            "assets.adobedtm.com", "codepushupdates.azureedge.net", "app-measurement.com",
            "forter.com", "dmn1", "dmn2", "dmn3", "quantummetric.com", "urbanairship.com", "demdex.net", "search.unbxd.io",
            "monetate.net", "bazaarvoice.com", "google.com", "stylitics.com", "getcandid.com","braintreegateway.com"
          };

          for (String host : hostList) {
            if (host.contains(arg0) || arg0.endsWith(host)) {
              return true;
            }
          }
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
```

What should I change, please help.

Comment: Post the full stack trace/error message.  Bad implementation btw.  Use a HashSet instead of an array and you can do on O(1) check instead of an O(n).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion will work on that. Full error,Your app is using an unsafe implementation of hostname verifier. Please see this Google Help Centre article for details, including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.

Ld/a/a/a/a/c/e$1;
Ld/a/a/a/a/c/f$1;
sv:deadline:12/10/2020

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the reason why, but looking again your implementation is insecure.  A page "mymalwaresite.com/google.com" would pass.At the very least you should parse the string into a URL and check the actual host, not do a .contains()

Comment: I tried making the check very generic by removing contains but even that did not work, got the exact same error.
public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession arg1) {
        if (hostname.equalsIgnoreCase("domain")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On google play console go to Release Management -> Select apk version -> Security tab. There you will see list of security issues with that apk along with class in your code that's causing that security issue where ever possible.

If you do not see a class name and rather see some encoded code in the security warning message, upload another build by disabling whatever code compress tool you maybe using. In my case it was proguard, I disabled it and got the library name. FYI - THe library was Braintree in my case

Answer (score 0):

The security alert is correct.  Your code is putting users at risk and *should* be rejected from the App Store.

Why do you need this code at all?  Remove it and only connect to servers when you get valid certificates back.